# How to measure/profile "Datastore Reads/Writes" from a single request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The "[new pricing model](http://www.google.com/enterprise/cloud/appengine/pricing.html)" has resources "Datastore Reads" and "Datastore Writes". But I could not find detailed information on exactly how this is measured.

Hard to optimize datastore utilization if I can not profile it! Any clues on how to do that? http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/managing-resources.html doesnt give any details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you trying AppStats, it can help you: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html

With this software you can profiling all API call.

Comment: Thanks, this helps but I still not sure how each API call is counted as a "Datastore Read/Write"